# Write left half of every line in file to one file and the right side to another

Tags: python, file

I'm looking to create a program that will take any file and split the characters in the file into two separate files corresponding to the left and right side of any line. I've written this so far but I've gotten stuck. Any adivice would be appreciated

source

```
$cat > foo
abcdef
ghijkl
```

desired result:

```
print(foe)
abcghi

print(fum)
defjkl
```

foo = open(foo)

```
def write_left(foo):
    foo_linse=file_len(foo)
    foe = ''
    fum = ''
    with open(foo) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            while i <= foo_lines:
            x = len(line)
            mid = int(x/2) - 1
                foe = foe.append(foo[:mid])
                fum = fum.append(fo0[mid:])


write_left(foo)
```

Comment: Could you post also what is the result of the function and also how it should be?

Comment: You haven't actually opened any files for writing. If you did, you'd be 95% of the way there; you just `write` (possibly adding newlines as needed) instead of appending to unnecessary `list`s. It would also make sense to write both left and right at once, so you're not wasting your time scanning through the input twice.

Comment: @RafaelRodrigoDeSouza, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def left_right(filename):
    import re
    parsefl = open(str(filename), "r")
    left = []
    right = []
    for line in parsefl:
        numRead = int(len(line) / 2)
        rightRead = re.sub("\n", "", line[numRead:])
        line = re.sub(rightRead, '', line)
        leftRead = re.sub("\n", "", line)
        right.append(rightRead)
        left.append(leftRead)
    parsefl.close()
    return left, right
```

Specify the filename you want to separate when calling the function like: `left_right("file_to_parse")`. This function returns a tuple of lists, the first list being the left side of the file, and the second being the right side of the file.